# How to move the fieldEditor to selected position?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsevent

When I tried to edit the column using `-(void)editColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)select` of `NSTableView` the field editor always comes at the beginning of the `NSTextField`.I inserted some tab spaces for the text. I would like to move the field editor(cursor) to the start of the text. Any hints to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean move the Field Editor _selection_? (Or actually change the frame of the field editor?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue using the following code.

```
[[self.tableView currentEditor] setString:@"YourStringValue"];
```